# UtteranceProgressListener won't call the functions

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to make a speech powered app, however I have run into a major problem.


My `UtteranceProgressListener` Class will not call any of the given methods regardless of where I place the Speak method.

Here is my code:

This is my OnCreate Method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    voiceBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startListeningBtn);

    voiceBtn.setEnabled(false);
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(mContext,new botListener());

  }
```

---

This is the OnInitListner Imeplementation

```
public class botListener implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {

        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            int s = textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done Speaking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done Speaking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(s));

            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                Log.e(TAG,"Language not supported");
                Intent installLanguage = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installLanguage);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Started Voice Speaker");
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG,"initialization failed");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, when I press the button, the event that fires is:

```
public void initVoiceRecog(View v){
    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Speak("hello","1");
    // does some other things here after that 

}

private void Speak(String text,String identifierID){

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>21) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,identifierID);
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, identifierID);
    }
    else{
    // ttsMap is a HashMap
    ttsMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,identifierID);
    textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,ttsMap );
    }
}
```

---

My Question is, after saying hello, it does not fire the `OnStart()` or the `OnError()` or the `OnDone()` methods. Why is this happening?

I tried with the deprecated `setOnUtteranceListner()` as well, same result. It does not fire any of the methods, the Toasts don't show up.

Please tell a fix or a workaround for this.

The Devices I tried on are:

API 19 Micromax Canvas Nitro

API 21 Samsung S4

API 23(Marshmellow) ASUS Zenfone

Comment: Nothing looks wrong, but try moving your ProgressListener outside of onInit - by that I mean let you main activity implement both instead of the botListener class

Comment: My activity is extending appcompatactivity and I cannot extend the utteranceprogresslistener. So how do I do it?

Comment: Ok, I tried that but still no result. I have as of now, kept the utteranceProgressListener in the OnInit. No luck.

Comment: Have you tried using **only** the code you've posted in a test Activity? I assume you must be doing other things that could be causing the problem. Are you doing anything in `onPause` or `onResume`? Have you tried a different TTS Engine? Does `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` return ERROR or SUCCESS?

Comment: Yes I am using exactly this code, the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` returns SUCCESS, I am using the google TTS engine. But still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out why the callbacks were not working. Turns out, they were working and calling on a separate thread. So to execute the normal functionality, call the functions in the 'Activity.this.RunOnUiThread' and put this in the call back fuctions.