# Can´t call Speechrecognizer.startListening(Intent) from UtteranceProgressListener onDone() function

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-text-to-speech

I have set up Google Speech in my project.

When I run the Speechrecognizer.startListening() method from the mainActivity

after clicking a Button it starts the recognition, gets the results, all works well.

I am putting out speech after I have some results, I use a custom UtteranceProgressListener to be able to detect if Text to speech is finished.
After text to speech has finished I want to call startListening again, but if I call startListening() from the UtteranceProgressListener classes onDone function nothing happens.

(the onDone method of the utteranceProgressListener is called correctly, tested it using the Debugger )

Is there a way to send some kind of event back to my main activity from the uterranceProgressListener, so I can call startListening from my main activity again? ( where it should be called ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UtteranceProgressListener won't call the functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230914/utteranceprogresslistener-wont-call-the-functions)

Answer (score -1):

I was an idiot, the problem was I was not returning to the main Thread from the listener, I am terribly sorry, this question should be deleted.